# Javascript DOM manipulation while EJS loop

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have few hours on this problem and I am still stuck on it, can't seem to find a solution.
In short, I am trying to manipulate each div from an EJS loop. I simplified the problem so can be easier to understand.

```
  <% for(let i of products) { %>
        <div> 
           // products irrelevant code
        </div>

        <div  class="d-flex justify-content-around">
            <i class="btn btn-light fas fa-heart fa-lg" id="wishlist" style="color:grey;"></i>
        </div>
    <% } %>


    <script>
        const heart = document.getElementById("wishlist")
      
        heart.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        heart.style.color = "red";
      });
      
    </script>
```

On my showpage, when I click on the element it changes the color as it should, but just for the first product. I am not sure why is not hitting each div in the loop.
How can I change the color for each specific element?

Comment: IDs need to be unique, use a class and delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove id `wishlist` on `i` and add `container` id for parent div.

AddEventListener on `container` id div, and modify target clicked element as shown in below code.

```js
const heart = document.getElementById("container");
heart.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('fa-heart')) {
    tgt.style.color = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />

<div id="container">
  <div>
    // products irrelevant code
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around" id="container">
    <i class="btn btn-light fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color:grey;"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    // products irrelevant code
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <i class="btn btn-light fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color:grey;"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    // products irrelevant code
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <i class="btn btn-light fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color:grey;"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because IDs need to be unique and it is better to delegate

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work, still works just for the first element..

Comment: Container is ALSO duplicated - it is in a loop. Wrap the LOOP in a div with id=container